# Значение слова "бусый"

Tags: значение-слов

В темнице там царевна тужит,
А бусый волк ей верно служит.

```
 Так ли это на самом деле? Вот прочла где-то и сидит в голове. Действительно ли так у Пушкина?
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет, у Пушкина - "бурый", вот даже почти научная статья об этом (почему не "серый"):

https://cyberleninka.ru/article/v/buryy-volk

Видимо, случилась ошибка программы автоматического распознавания текста.